# Simple Looping In Java Script

Tags: javascript

I made a simple loop and would like to know how to carry this out.

The variable's name is Math, and it is equal to 4. I am trying to write a simple looping statement that says: "While Math is not equal to 4, await your number"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var math = 2+2;

var loop = function(){
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{

    while (math[i] != 4)
    {
        console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
    }

}
};

loop();
```

Comment: math is not array.

Comment: reconsider the use of the word Math.  it is reserved for the built in object that exposes mathematical functions, like sin, or rand.

Comment: You also have one extra semicolon after `i++`

Comment: why are you  using while instead of IF

Comment: You never change the value of math. I'm not sure what you wanna do, can you show us some example output with multiple logs?

Comment: I'm trying to get the while to work in this context.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to loop through 0-5 and while it is not equal to 4, I  want it to print "Await until you reach 4" in the console.

Comment: @EdwardK. you wil lrun an infinite  loop is you will use WHILE

Comment: Try: `if (i != math)` so the loop stops when `i` equals `math`.

Comment: @MörreNoseshine No it doesn't. This is on the very edge of being "example code", and additionally, this code doesn't work. Please [be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: What doo you actually want? You write that the user should wait until `math` (poor name indeed) would have the value `4` but you only set math once ?!?. Do you want to react on the loop iteration counter reaching the value of `math`? Do you want a busy wait for user input? Define precisely what you want before 'getting [insert your favorite programming construct] to work' - if you can't phrase what you want,bets are on that you haven't grasped some concept or the problem to solve.

Comment: The point is I learned a lot from this post and so do other users, so why does it not belong on StackExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you presumably want:

```
var math = 2+2;

var loop = function(){
    var i = 0;
    while (i !== math) {
        i++;
        console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
    }
}

loop();
```

Note that technically, the `for` loop in javascript (as well as in many other languages) actually is not that much different from a `while` loop, as the code for  initialization, increment and termination is rather unrestricted. You are not even forced to have an iteration variable in you `for` loop.

The difference is in someone else's ease of understanding of your code (or your's after you haven't looked into you code for some time). `for` suggests a counted iteration of a list, `while` some operations to be performed while (sic!) a condition is fulfilled without which the operation make no sense or produce the wrong result.

Comment: You got it man, that is what I was trying to do, using the "while" function.

Answer (score 1):

This concept will create an endless loop, that waits for something to edit the variable.

As javascript occupies the thread its running in, all events will be waiting for this endless loop to end.

If it's part of the main GUI thread, (normal javascript) this means that your page will hang. Only use this method for webworkers, or extensions.

Instead redesign as eventhandlers, instead of a main loop

edit: having read your comments, and found out what you are trying to do:

```
var math = 2+2;
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   if(i != math){
       console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
       continue
   }
   alert("yay")
}
```

or with a while loop

```
var math = 2+2;

var i = 0;
while(math != i){
   if(i != math){
       console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
   }
   i++;
}
alert("yay")
```

Comment: Good job. It is interesting that in the "For" statement, you have to declare the variable to 0 and have it iterate through a slew of numbers.

Now for the "While" statement, you simply incremented " i ++" and it knew to start from 0, and work its way up to 4.

Comment: it would be interesting if it was the case, but I wouldnt count on it, and in fact I did not in the answer, I declared "i" before I entered the while loop..

Comment: True, but you didn't have to do the " i < 5 " like in the 'For' statement. I tried deleting the " i < 5 " from the 'For' statement and it would not run.

Comment: :)  that is because the for loop, can be understood like this: **start with first expression** then **while second expression** do {`code` and **third statement**}

Comment: Can you explain why my original code is causing an infinite loop? In the For statement before it, I say for it to stop before 5. 

It eventually reaches 4. Yet the while loop keeps going. So I assume I have to put a stop to it within the while loop. 

It appears that a while loop is infinite in its nature, EVEN IF, the condition is met ( !=4)

Comment: First, your "while loop" is nested within the for loop. This means that for each run of the for loop, the while loop starts from it's beginning. That means that if the while loop never exits, the for loop never gets to it's second run..

Comment: Second, your while loop never changes the "i" variable, and it continues to run as long as i is different from math, which you also never change..

Comment: Third, you are trying to access the i'th member of an array `Math[i]`that would resolve to "undefined" as Math is not an array. so even if you did update i in the while loop (notice that I do this) you would never actually read a value from Math. Instead treat Math as the number it is (like I do)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do:

```
var math = 2+2;
var loop = function(){
for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    if(i != math){
        console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
    }else{
        console.log("You have reached 4");
    }
};

loop();
```

Using while

```
var math = 2+2;
var loop = function(){
   var i=0;
   while(i != math){
      console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
      i++;
   }
};

loop();
```

Comment: That does the same thing, but I wanted to see how to do it using the while statement without the if.

Answer (score -1):

```
var loop = function(math){
   var i = 0;
   while(i!==math){
      console.log ("Await until you reach 4");
      i++;
   }
}
loop(2+2);
```

Comment: There is no explanation with your code and the function() is removed. Can you extend your answer?

Comment: @Mast you can wrap this code in a function, he probably left it out because it's trivial. The rest is basic logic: while `i` is not equal to 4 (`math`), it will print the message and increment `i` by one.

Comment: what explanation you need you just need to call loop function wherever you want and pass any number as parameter